# Fetch signature from IONOS webmail

Tags: python, smtp, ionos

I am using SMTP in Python to send the emails from IONOS webmail and it is working fine. However, I would need to send emails with the signature that I have setup in IONOS webmail and I cant find a way to fetch that signature with Image. Please help out.